# EntityFramework Any generates two EXISTS sql statements

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I want to use the LINQ 'Any' method with EntityFramework to check the existence of a record.

Even with the most basic query:

```
DbContext.Users.Any()
```

The SQL statement generated by EF looks like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS [C1] FROM [dbo].[User] AS [Extent1])) THEN cast(1 as bit) 
WHEN (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS [C1] FROM [dbo].[User] AS [Extent2])) THEN cast(0 as bit) 
END AS [C1]
```

Can I force EF to generate a single EXISTS statement, like this ?

```
SELECT
    (CASE
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            FROM [User] AS [t0]
            ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END) AS [value]
```

UPDATE

In the following link, EF generates a single EXISTS statement: http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2013/04/use-any-in-your-linq-to-sql-queries.html.

I'm using EF 6.1.0 so looks like older versions did generate a single statement ?

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: You can always use StoredProcedures or raw sql to force it to do something. If you suspect this is a problem I would start by looking at the execution plans. Suprisingly enough ugly sql is not always slow sql

Comment: I would put a lot of money on this not being, in any way, an actual issue. In SQL, you tell the system what you want, not how to do it. And even if the server does, boneheadedly, query the table twice, it completes each `EXISTS` as soon as it has located one row. There are no filters. So it maybe reads one row from the table twice rather than once. Is it worth fussing over?

Comment: If you don't like this, you are going to freak the **** out when you see what EF generates when faced with more complex queries. Embrace it. You're basically like an Assembly programmer freaking out when they see the inefficient Assembly that C++ compilers come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in EF 6.1 so by just upgrading you would get better generated queries.

If you cannot upgrade, maybe you can rewrite the C# code to force EF to generate a better SQL query.

DbContext.Users.Count() > 0

This will perform better than the other one but worse than the query generated by EF 6.1.